# Hibernate - Boilerplate code for transactions

Tags: hibernate, transactions, crud, boilerplate

I have written this service class for database CRUD operations.

visible    public class CompanyServiceImpl extends PersistentRemoteService implements CompanyService {

```
    private GileadHibernateUtil gileadHibernateUtil;

    public CompanyServiceImpl() {
        gileadHibernateUtil = new GileadHibernateUtil();
        setBeanManager(gileadHibernateUtil.getPersistentBeanManager());
    }

    @Override
    public void addCompany(Company newCompany) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(newCompany, "newCompany is null.");

        Session session = gileadHibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.persist(newCompany);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            if (transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
            session.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Company updateCompany(Company company) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(company, "company is null.");

        Session session = gileadHibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        Company managedCompany = null;

        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            managedCompany = (Company) session.merge(company);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            if (transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }

        return managedCompany;
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteCompany(Company company) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(company, "company is null.");

        Session session = gileadHibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;

        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(company);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            if (transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Company findCompany(int companyId) {
        if (companyId <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("companyId must be a positive integer.");
        }

        Session session = gileadHibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        Company company = null;

        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            company = (Company) session.get(Company.class, companyId);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            if (transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }
        return company;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Company> findMatchingCompanies(String companyName) {

        Session session = gileadHibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        List<Company> matchingCompanies = null;

        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria searchCriteria = session.createCriteria(Company.class).add(
                    Restrictions.or(Restrictions.like("code", companyName), Restrictions.like("name", companyName)));
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            matchingCompanies = searchCriteria.list();
        } finally {
            if (transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }

        return matchingCompanies;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Company> findAllCompanies() {

        Session session = gileadHibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction transaction = null;
        List<Company> companies = null;

        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            Criteria searchCriteria = session.createCriteria(Company.class);
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            companies = searchCriteria.list();
        } finally {
            if (transaction.isActive()) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        }
        return companies;
    }

}
```

I decided to not use a separate DAO layer. Its a small app and I am not going to switch from Hibernate. All it would have included was Hibernate session commands. Beginning and ending a transaction still comes in business layer. So, Hibernate pretty much works as the DAO layer for me.
What's pinching me is the seemingly boilerplate code for transactions, which has to be written in every CRUD method.
Is this any better way, or is this the minimum amount of code that is going to be repeated no matter what?

Comment: Have you considered using Spring's Hibernate support framework?

Comment: @ToddMurray For now, its not an option. That's the main issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using spring and are able to use annotations.  There is a good article on the link provided which shows how to use annotations to wrap a method in a transaction.

http://springinpractice.com/2008/03/18/annotation-based-transactions-in-spring/

using spring and hibernate together would make your code look cleaner and would look something like what is below.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public void addCompany(Company newCompany) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(newCompany, "newCompany is null.");
    Session session = gileadHibernateUtil.getCurrentSession();
    session.persist(newCompany);
    //session.close(); this line would also not be needed because the session would close automatically when the transaction is complete.
}
```

Comment: Yeah. I read that at several places that Spring will help clean up code. But, I am not supposed to use Spring for now. What are my options then?

Comment: Not sure what other alternatives there are out there for a declarative type of transaction.  You may want to try some sort of aop solution. But that would also require another library which you may not be able to use like AspectJ.

Comment: OK. I guess I will wait for a day before accepting this as the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without spring something like this can be done using

`java.util.function.Function`

```
 public static Object transactionExecutor(Function<Session, Object> toRun) {
    Session session = null;
    Object result = null;
    try {
        session = getSession();
        final Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        result = toRun.apply(session);
        session.flush();
        tx.commit();
        return result;
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        Transaction tx = session.getTransaction();
        tx.rollback();
    } finally {

        session.close();
    }
    return result;
 }


 public static void save(final Students S) {
    Function<Session, Object> toRun = new Function<Session, Object>() {
        @Override
        public Object apply(final Session t) {
        t.save(S);
        return S.getId();
        }
    };
    int saveID = (int)transactionExecutor(toRun);
 }
```