# How do i reduce bioler plate code in my hibernate based dao implementation

Tags: java, hibernate

I wrote an hibernate based implementation of one of my dao interface, but now i realize that there are plenty of code which are repeatative, like opening sesison, beginning ransaction, commit and rollback, each and every method having the same code, i want to know the way where can i keep that in one place, i heard about something called AbstractDao, but how that concept fit here, is it really work, i want to reduce the boiler plate code.

here is my snippet of implementation class

```
package com.javarnd.cip.dao;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.javarnd.cip.db.HibernateUtil;
import com.javarnd.cip.model.Sports;

public class SportsDaoImpl implements SportsDao {

    public void save(Sports sports) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(sports);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }

    public List<Sports> findAll() {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        List<Sports> sportsList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            sportsList = session.createQuery("FROM Sports", Sports.class).list();
            session.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
                return null;
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return sportsList;

    }

    public void update(Sports sports) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Sports sportsData = session.get(Sports.class, sports.getSportId());
            sportsData.setName(sports.getName());
            session.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    public void delete(Sports sports) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();

            Sports sportsData = session.get(Sports.class, sports.getSportId());
            session.delete(sportsData);

            session.getTransaction().commit();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Sports findById(long sportsId) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        Sports sportsData = null;
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            sportsData = session.get(Sports.class, sportsId);
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (tx != null) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        return sportsData;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can make use of spring-data-jpa and use `JpaRepository`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14566701/hibernate-boilerplate-code-for-transactions

Comment: I m not using Spring framework.

Comment: I am looking for some kind of util class which can have all those lines of code placed inside it and i can able to extend or call the method of the same, any suggestion is always welcome

Answer (score 0):

if you could use java 8, it could be look like this:

```
private static <OUTPUT> OUTPUT runInTransaction(Function<Session, OUTPUT> function) {
    Transaction tx = null;
    try (Session session = HibernateUtil.openSession()) {
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        final OUTPUT result = function.apply(session);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (tx != null) {
            tx.rollback();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
runInTransaction(session -> {
    return session.get(Sports.class, sportsId);
});
```

Comment: how do i get the respective types, like list of sports, sports object and void too

Comment: edited. Generic `OUTPUT` represents your output, so you could return anything you want. for `void` just return null and `OUTPUT` will be just `Object`

Comment: ohkk thanks so much i will implement the same and will observe the impact